# Add class to pagination links at CakePHP 2.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I can add a class ("myclass") to the link (previous or next) which does not contain a link.(current page) I just add the class following the default ones:

```
echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ', array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled myClass'));
```

And it generates something like this:

```
<span class="prev myClass disabled ">prev</span>
```

But, when the *previous* or the *next* links have a link, then i the class is not added and it generates something like this:

```
<span class="prev">
    <a href="/tickets/tickets/index/page:1?url=tickets" rel="prev">prev</a>
</span>
```

How can i add a class in this cases to this pagination links?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not `span.prev a`? With Paginator, you always add class to `span`, not to link, even disabled or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[API](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelperprev) Says the second parameter is an array for the link options so I guess you could do that:

```
echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ', array('class' => 'myLinkClass'), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled myClass'));
```

Comment: and how to add a class to `<a>` when generating `numbers()`? I didn't see that in API docs