# cakephp 2.x pagination with custom ul

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I need to generate html tags like the below .. to be precise, i need to add a class to the anchor tag added to the list, but i dnt seem to get it to work ..

```
<li class="myLIPrevclass"><a href="#" class="myAPREVClass"></a></li>

<li><a href="#" class="active">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>

<li class="myLINextclass"><a href="#" class="myANEXTClass"></a></li>
```

The challenge is,

1. i cant seem to get a class across to the a tag in the next and the previous, i need to solve this
2. Even if i leave the a tag blank for the previous and next, CakePHP goes ahead and adds a '>' or '<' which in my case I do not need.

This is what I have tried ..

```
<?php
echo $this->Paginator->prev(
  __(''), 
  array(
    'tag' => 'li',  
        'class' => 'previous',
   ), 
  __(''),
  array(
       'tag' => 'li',
   'class' => ''
  )
    );

echo $this->Paginator->numbers(
     array(
    'separator' => '',
    'tag' => 'li',
        'currentClass' => 'active',
    'currentTag'    => 'a'
   )
     );

echo $this->Paginator->next(
  __(''), 
  array(
    'tag' => 'li',  
        'class' => 'next',
  ), 
  __(''),
  array(
        'tag' => 'li',
    'class' => ''
  )
     );                     
?>
```

For the disabled titles (for both previous and next) even if i pass in null, Cake add a '>' or '<', and I don't want that

I have checked 
[Creating Pagination With CakePHP For Custom Template Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181340/creating-pagination-with-cakephp-for-custom-template-links)
and 
[Add class to pagination links at CakePHP 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643410/add-class-to-pagination-links-at-cakephp-2-2)

My Cake Version is 2.4.x

I'll appreciate any pointers or help ..
Thanks

Comment: can you some example url you want?

Comment: i want in the previous link for example

    `<li class="customClass1"><a href="#" class="customClass2"></a></li>`